# How to make sure a certain .js file is always loaded using wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin that is loading a specific .js file. Sometimes this file isn't loaded and is causing critical errors on my site.

It seems to work 90/100 times and I can't reproduce the issue but some customers are experiencing issues and the plugin itself mentions that .js isn't always loaded.

I don't use any caching plugins. And I can't find any caching settings anywhere.

Is there a way to force WordPress to always load that specific .js file?

Answer (score 0):

These might help in figuring out the issue.

1. Check the Plugin Settings: First, check if the plugin that is
   supposed to load the JavaScript file has any settings related to
   script loading. Some plugins provide options to enable or disable
   certain scripts. Ensure that the script you need is enabled in the
   plugin settings.
2. Use the wp_enqueue_script Function: You can use the
   wp_enqueue_script function in your theme's functions.php file to
   enqueue the JavaScript file manually. This will ensure that the
   script is loaded on every page where it's needed. Here's an example
   of how to enqueue a script:

```
function enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script-handle', 'path-to-your-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script');
```

3. Check for Plugin Conflicts: Sometimes, conflicts between plugins can
   prevent scripts from loading. Try disabling other plugins one by one
   to see if the issue persists. If the script loads consistently after
   disabling a specific plugin, that plugin might be the cause of the
   problem.
4. Use a Child Theme: If you're using a custom theme, make sure you're
   not modifying the parent theme directly. Instead, create and use a
   child theme for any customizations. Modifying the parent theme
   directly can sometimes lead to script loading issues.
5. Server-Side Caching: Although you mentioned you're not using caching
   plugins, it's possible that your hosting provider has server-side
   caching enabled. Contact your hosting provider to check if they have
   any server-level caching that could affect script loading.
6. Browser Cache: Ask affected customers to clear their browser caches
   and try accessing your site again. Sometimes, old cached versions of
   pages can lead to script loading issues.
7. CDN Issues: If you're using a Content Delivery Network (CDN), it's
   possible that the CDN is causing intermittent script loading issues.
   Check your CDN settings and purge any cached content if necessary.
8. Check for JavaScript Errors: Use browser developer tools to check
   for JavaScript errors in the browser console. These errors can
   sometimes provide clues about why a script is not loading or
   functioning correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

1) No options available
2) I'm not sure what data I need to provide for "your script handle"  but this might seem like a good option to try
3) The problem is: it's working fine every time I test it. Only other users report problems, but not all time only a few cases (probably 15 out of 100).
5) I checked the hosting party and they do provide caching options but all are disabled by default
6) That might be an issue but that's beyond my control. Because it's a new user every time.
8) The required file is always loaded when I check.

Thanks!

Comment: I added the enqued_custom_script, is there any way to test if this is working?

Comment: on your WordPress website where you expect the script to be loaded.
Right-click on the page and select "View Page Source".
Search for the script tag for enqued_custom_script

Another option can be add a console.log in your script that is being loaded and check that gets logged.

Comment: Does not seem to get loaded, I placed the following in functions.php:

function enqueue_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('public_test', '/wp-content/plugins/paytium-pro/public/js/public.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script');

Is this correct?